# Underscore in numeric literals

Tags: java, variables, java-7

On official [Java site](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html) I came across this lines

```
    you cannot place underscores in the following places:

     At the beginning or end of a number...
```

Also they have given a example

```
int x1 = _52;              // This is an identifier, not a numeric literal
```

When I used it in my code it didn't gave any compile time error

```
long l = _23L;
```

Can we use `_` at the beginning?
What does it mean by

```
This is an identifier, not a numeric literal
```

Sorry if it is a really silly question, I haven't revised Java basics from long time.

**EDIT :**
I am using Windows XP and Java 7

```
java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: What compiler are you using, and in which OS? That really should give a compile error, but as Rajendran T noted, not a type error but an unknown variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Literals** are any thing which you hardcoded in the code like:

```
int x  = 10;
String str = "hello";
```

In this `10` and `hello` are literals.

So **numeric literal** is nothing but literal having numerical value.

Identifiers are names given to objects, classes etc. but cannot be `keywords` like int, boolean, null etc.

So in above example `x, str and String` are identifiers.

SIDE NOTE: How you define numerical literals are different from JDK 6 to JDK 7. So code in question will only run for JDK7

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "What does it mean by
`This is an identifier, not a numeric literal`" clearly.

Comment: by identifier it means it is a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

> When I used it in my code it didn't gave any compile time error
>
> long l = _23L;

It means you should have some long variable named `_23L` somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to recheck your test case.

I get this, expected, error when I try to compile this.

```
ariel-2:src boxcat$ javac scratch/misc/ScratchSO.java 
scratch/misc/ScratchSO.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        long l = _23L;
                 ^
  symbol:   variable _23L
  location: class ScratchSO
1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

An identifier is like a variable name or an object name: http://java.about.com/od/i/g/identifier.htm

Answer (score 0):

Java 7 has now allowed underscores in numeric literals.

```
int i = 1_000_000;  // readable.
```